# How to import bundle created in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have a **Project1** which is bundled through webpack. My requirement is that this bundle.js will be put on a CDN so that I can use the modules exported in Project 1 inside **Project2**.

*Project 1 files* ->

**Hello.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Hello extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.js:**

```
export {Hello} from "./src/Hello.jsx";
```

---

I am creating a bundle named **bundle.js** and for demo purposes, instead of adding it in the CDN, I am simply copying this **bundle.js**(in same folder as App.jsx) and referring it in **Project2**.

*Project 2 files* ->

**App.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Hello from "./bundle.js";

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Hello/>
        );
    }
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./src/App.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root2")
);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>webpack 2 demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root2">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to run **Project2** using webpack-dev-server with HMR enabled but it gives errors in Google Chrome console:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

- Current versions of packages:

> "react": "^15.4.2"
>   "webpack": "^2.2.1",
>   "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
>   "babel-core": "^6.24.0"

Am I doing Import in a wrong fashion? Or is there something wrong in Export? Please help.

Edit:
Adding webpack.config.js for **Project1** as Joe Clay [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949247/how-to-import-bundle-created-in-webpack#comment72993866_42949247):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'Hello'
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react'
    })
  ],
};
```

Comment: Can you please include the `webpack.config.js` for Project1?

Comment: what you need to do is `import { Hello } from './bundle'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import {Hello} from "./bundle.js";
```

You are not exporting `Hello` as default.

```
export {Hello} from "./src/Hello.jsx";
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to do this you need to update your webpack config to output a bundle that can be exported.

Your config needs to have these lines

```
{
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'umd', // make the bundle export
        externals: {
            'react': { // import react from an external module so you don't have multiple instances
                'commonjs': 'react', 
                'amd': 'react'
             },
            'react-dom': { // some versions of react had links to react-dom so its good to include this
                'commonjs': 'react-dom',
                'amd': 'react-dom'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to note that if you are using create-react-app for your project you will need to eject your subproject to change your config

Comment: Your solution helped me ! Thank you so much for sharing this.

Comment: Thanks! In case you are developing a node project and not a web project you will also run into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639839/typescript-webpack-library-generates-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined

Answer (score 4):

This article helped me with creating an importable/exportable library that is bundled by webpack.

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-library-starter-using-webpack-es6

You need something like this in your webpack config file:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/lib',
    filename: outputFile,
    library: libraryName,    // very important line
    libraryTarget: 'umd',    // very important line
    umdNamedDefine: true     // very important line
  },
```