# Typescript + Webpack library generates "ReferenceError: self is not defined"

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm building a TS library bundled with Webpack 5.3.2. I then try to load the output bundle, `dist/scalextric.js`, into a `node.js` script:

```
node -e 'console.dir(Object.keys(require("./dist/scalextric.js")));'
```

I get:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/kratib/Data/src/infojunkie/scalextric/dist/scalextric.js:2:215)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at [eval]:1:25
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:132:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
```

I need help fixing this error. Here are my various configs:

- `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'scalextric.js',
    library: 'Scalextric',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    umdNamedDefine: true,
  },
};
```

- `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

- `index.ts`:

```
export * from './Tuning';
export * from './TuningNotation';
export * from './Interval';
```

Any obvious mistake I am making? [Here's the full code](https://github.com/infojunkie/scalextric).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This issue is related to the option `output.globalObject` of which is [described here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject).

I believe `webpack` has set it as `self` for a certain reason. But in order to work on browser and node you can simply switch to `this`:

```js
output: {
  // ...
  globalObject: 'this',
},
```