# Webpack'd oboe module will not run

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've compiled a project using webpack, which among its dependencies has [oboe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oboe). After including the compiled project as a dependency in a node project, and starting it up with `npm run dev`, I get this error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@myproject/blockchain/lib/@myproject/blockchain.js:37762
         return self;
         ^

ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

Looking at that bit of code in the compiled project, I find

```
// Access to the window object throws an exception in HTML5 web workers so
// point it to "self" if it runs in a web worker
try {
    return window;
} catch (e) {
    return self;
}
```

Seems like this is some kind of Webpack *feature*, but I'm not sure how to cope with it. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639839/typescript-webpack-library-generates-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined), but looking at my current configuration for `globalObject`:

```
globalObject: 'typeof self !== \'undefined\' ? self : this'
```

that does not seem to be the right answer. I looked through the [output configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) of Webpack, but not sure what I'm looking for.

Any idea how I can include oboe as a dependency such that it will run in a webpack compiled project?

Comment: I'm not sure how `oboe` factors into anything here...

Comment: Codesandbox uses Webpack for bundling and simply using Oboe there works just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/oboe-webpack-works-n80l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @AKX oboe is the package that is blowing up in the compiled code. Also, it doesn't look like we can see the compiled code on codesandbox nor their webpack config. Not sure how to go about solving this issue...

Comment: Ahh, looks like it's in [the dist of oboe 2.1.4](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js/blob/v2.1.4/dist/oboe-browser.js#L2699). I wonder why others are not facing this problem... I'm running on node, don't even need the browser code; frustrating.

Comment: And of course using your example in codesandbox w/ oboe 2.1.4 works since `window` is defined....

Comment: I assume you have a reason to webpack code for Node.js..?

Comment: That's the callout I was looking for! This probably the first package I've built that only needs to run on node. Previously I have been using a webpack boilerplate to build packages. Thanks @AKX

Comment: Heh, glad I could help in a roundabout way :)