# Jest fails with 'self is not defined' when importing react-diagrams

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

Im trying to create a basic jest test interacting with a npm dependency: [react-diagrams](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams)

#### The failing test

```
import { DiagramModel } from '@projectstorm/react-diagrams'

test('importing react diagrams', () => {
    let x = DiagramModel
});
```

Simply referencing the `DiagramModel` class causes this error:

```
    ReferenceError: self is not defined

    > 1 | import { DiagramModel } from '@projectstorm/react-diagrams'
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | test('importing react diagrams', () => {
      4 |     let x = DiagramModel

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@projectstorm/react-diagrams/dist/index.umd.js:1:331)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/DiagramModel.test.ts:1:1)
```

Other tests works fine, and the dependency works fine when bundeled elsewhere.

#### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

#### package.json

```
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.5.2",
...
```

Any ideas what I can do to remedy this?

#### Reproducing

Added test + configuration in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-test-self-is-not-defined-bw7hn) (but could not get the test runner to pick it up). The full [repo](https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639839/typescript-webpack-library-generates-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined

Comment: You will need to provide a reproductible example because as you can see on [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-river-fdhpd?file=/src/App.test.js) there is no such problem at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some tests it finally works with this configuration :

### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

### package.json :

```
{
  "name": "jest-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@projectstorm/react-canvas-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@projectstorm/react-diagrams": "^6.5.2",
    "@projectstorm/react-diagrams-routing": "^6.5.2",
    "closest": "^0.0.1",
    "dagre": "^0.8.5",
    "pathfinding": "^0.4.18",
    "paths-js": "^0.4.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

You were missing the fact that `@projectstorm/react-diagrams` is a `react` library and it needs `dom` environment not `nodejs`.

Comment: I updated my answer to test if it's related to Jest testEnvironment, let me know if it works !

Comment: Lifesaver! I can award bounty in 24 hours :)